# unit testing a DAO method using mocked entity manager get issue when testing Exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, persistence

I have a simple DAO method that I'm trying to test:

```
public boolean insertUser (User user) throws DaoException {
    boolean result = false;

    try {
        em.persist(user);
        result = true;
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        throw new DaoException( e );
    }

    return result;
}
```

as persist can return an exception I want to unit test this case:

I have mocked the entity manager:

```
@Mock
EntityManager mockEm;
```

And my test:

```
@Test
public void testExceptionEntityExistInsertUser() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("entity already exist exception");
    boolean result;
    when(mockEm.persist(user)).thenThrow(EntityExistsException.class);
    result = userDao.insertUser(user);
}
```

But on line when(mockEm.persist(user)).thenThrow(EntityExistsException.class); I have the following error:
'void' type not allowed here

I don't understand where the issue come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to set a data of entity not allowed. For exemple a data to null when this data has @NotNull tag:

```
@Test
public void testExceptionEntityExistInsertUser() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("entity already exist exception");
    boolean result;
    user.setData(null) // assuming data has a NotNull tag
    result = userDao.insertUser(user);
}
```

Then test will generate an exception.